# How to hide & unhide the Master View Controller in a SplitView Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a Master Detail view controller, and I am trying to write a method/message which shows or hides the Master list. I have followed all the answers to [this almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020323/how-to-hide-unhide-master-view-controller-in-splitview-controller) but none of them work for me. I am developing for iOS6, but even still after following the advice of the answers that addressed this, I still get unhelpful `SIG_ABRT` errors.

Here is my code:

WWFMasterViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class WWFDetailViewController;
@interface WWFMasterViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) WWFDetailViewController *detailViewController;
@end
```

WWFMasterViewController.m:

```
#import "WWFMasterViewController.h"
#import "WWFDetailViewController.h"

@interface WWFMasterViewController ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray * arr;
@end

@implementation WWFMasterViewController
@synthesize arr;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    }
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    arr=@[@"First",@"Second",@"Third",@"Fourth",@"Fifth"];
    self.detailViewController = (WWFDetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return arr.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = arr[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = arr[indexPath.row];
    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:arr[indexPath.row]];
    }
}

@end
```

WWFDetailViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface WWFDetailViewController : UIViewController <UISplitViewControllerDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;
@end
```

WWFDetailViewController.m:

```
#import "WWFDetailViewController.h"

@interface WWFDetailViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *masterPopoverController;
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation WWFDetailViewController

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;
        [self configureView];
    }

    if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }        
}

- (void)configureView
{
    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self configureView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - Split view

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = nil;
}

- (BOOL) splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    return YES;
}

@end
```

How can I write a method/message for this code that will show/hide the Master list?

TIA

Comment: Did you create a project using the Apple master-detail template and look at how it works?

Comment: Yes I did. What am I missing?

Comment: On iPhone it's just push / pop the controller. On iPad you should have a nav bar button.

Comment: Show me the code to show/hide the master list and I will mark you as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Ive found out how to hide the master view controller in iOS6. This is the code I used:

```
[self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

And for showing the master view controller I am thinking this function is needed `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:` but I have not tested this yet.

This code goes into the DetailViewController.

Answer (score 2):

```
Use following method to hide the split view:

.h file must contain UISplitViewControllerDelegate

// In split delegate
- (void)hideMaster {

    [self.splitViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = nil;
    self.splitViewController.delegate = self;

    [self.splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:0];

}// end hideMaster


-(BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{

    return YES;

}

Use following method to show the split view:

// In split delegate
- (void)hideMaster {

    [self.splitViewController.view setNeedsLayout];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = nil;
    self.splitViewController.delegate = self;

    [self.splitViewController willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:0];

}// end hideMaster


-(BOOL)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc shouldHideViewController:(UIViewController *)vc inOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{

    return NO; // Important when show the split view again

}
```

//vKj