# Is it possible to close the menu ( split screen ) dynamically

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, rubymotion

I've been working on a RubyMotion project and I'm using the UISplitViewController, but I was wondering: is it possible to close the side screen ( so the screen that's hidden ) programmatically?

I guess this is a private API in iOS, but I'm not sure or this is true. I'm able to close the split screen with a tap on someplace else on the screen ( default iOS behavior ), but I can't find the function that creates that effect.

I've been searching on the web for this, but I couldn't find any answer to this question. Hope you guys can help me out.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish this, you will need to use the `UISplitViewController Delegate` and implement `splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation:`.

The assigned delegate could then have an attribute that is changed between `true/false` when a button is pressed.

In your `splitViewController:shouldHideViewController:inOrientation:` you would then return that attribute to say whether the master view should be shown or not.

Then finally, when the button is pressed, you will also need to call `setNeedsLayout` to force it to redraw and call the delegate method.

```
# Button Touch Handler
def hideShowMasterViewButtonPressed(sender)
  self.hideMasterView = !self.hideMasterView
  self.splitViewController.view.setNeedsLayout
end

# Delegate Method
def splitViewController(svc, shouldHideViewController:vc, inOrientation:orientation)
  self.hideMasterView
end
```

[This is where I got the idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827312/how-to-hide-unhide-the-master-view-controller-in-a-splitview-controller)